# How can I truncate centered text by letter with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have list of items, each one is a `div` with short text 1 or 2 words. Sometimes the text is too long and I need to cut the text.

I want the `div` to keep the text on a single line and if it is too long, cut the extra letters.

The problem with my solution is that text is in the middle so it is cutting from both the left and right, and it should only cut from the right (For example if my word is "elephant" I see "lephan" instead of "elepha").

The second problem with that solution is that it is not cutting letters but hiding the overflow, so I can see some parts of the cut letters. I know I can easily cut the text with JavaScript, but is there any solution for this with pure CSS?

```css
.listGroupItem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: clip;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<p class="listGroupItem">My elephant</p>
```

Comment: `justify-content:safe center;` would help in a few browsers ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this style:

```
.listGroupItem {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If you don't want text truncation, remove text-overflow: ellipsis;

Answer (score -1):

I think it works as you expected just out of the box. Take a look at this demo.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: bisque;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

.long-text {
  color: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
  <meta content="#000000" name="theme-color" />
  <meta content="Sandbox and previewer for ui experiments" name="description" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    function myFunction(value) {
      const myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
      const myWidth = myDiv.offsetWidth;
      myDiv.style.width = myWidth + value + "px";
    }
  </script>
  <title>Simple dimple</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="myDiv">
    <p class="text long-text">Hello</p>
    <p class="text long-text">ElephantElephantElephant</p>
    <p class="text long-text">Try it by yourself</p>
    <p class="text long-text">Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis</p>
  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(-10)">Shrink -10px</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction(10)">Expand +10px</button>

</body>

</html>
```